# CanJS findOne by name

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-model

I am using CanJS for a web application. I want to know how to implement search. I have implemented findAll but i want to implement findOne based on the name and not id.

```
var Library = can.Model({
    findAll:    "GET /libraries",
    findOne:    "GET/libraries/{id}",
    create:     'POST /libraries',
    update:     'PUT /libraries/{id}',
    destroy:    'DELETE /libraries/{id}'
}, {});
```

I want to implement findOne based on the name and not on ID. Can some one help me. I came accross Underscore.js. What are the other alternatives of finding based on the name.

`{      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "CanJS",
      "web" : "http://canjs.us",
        "logo": "img/can.png"
    },`

This is how the items in library look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it without rewrite findOne function:

```
MyModel.findOne({id:15,name:'canjs'})
```

the request will be mayendpoint?id=15&name=canjs

the Id is mandatory for RESTFUL resource if you want to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement findOne as you like, e.g. `findOne: 'GET /libraries/name/{name}'`. See [API documentation](http://donejs.com/docs.html#!can.Model.static.findOne).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement findOne with a function of your own as written [here](http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.findOne.html#section_ImplementwithaFunction)